# Error while finding similarity between polars dataframe column and string variable

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to find a similarity between the column in the polar data frame and the input value.I am using jaro_winkler_metric . I am getting errors while doing it. We don't want to use UDF functions as it slows the process.

```
import polars as pl
import jaro


def test_polars():
    name='savah'
    data = {"first_name": ['sarah', 'purnima'], "last_name": ['vats', 'malik']}
    df = pl.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
    df = df.with_columns(
        [
                    (pl.when( jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(pl.col("first_name"), name) >= 0.8
                          ).then(1).otherwise(0)).alias("COMP80_FN"),

        ]
    )

    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_polars()


C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Scripts\python.exe "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py" 
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│ first_name ┆ last_name │
│ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ str       │
╞════════════╪═══════════╡
│ sarah      ┆ vats      │
│ purnima    ┆ malik     │
└────────────┴───────────┘
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py", line 22, in <module>
    test_polars()
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\polars data.py", line 12, in test_polars
    (pl.when( jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(pl.col("first_name"), name) >= 0.8
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\jaro\__init__.py", line 43, in jaro_winkler_metric
    return jaro.metric_jaro_winkler(string1, string2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\jaro\jaro.py", line 235, in metric_jaro_winkler
    ans = string_metrics(string1, string2,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PythonProject\pythonProject\venv\Graph_POC\Lib\site-packages\jaro\jaro.py", line 159, in string_metrics
    assert isinstance(s1, str)
AssertionError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It needs to be written in Rust if you want to avoid a "slow UDF". There is a 3rd party plugin: https://github.com/ion-elgreco/polars-distance - source: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/plugins/#community-plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies within this snippet:

```
jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(pl.col("first_name"), name)
```

You pass a polars expression to `jaro_winkler_metric` and I doubt the function such inputs, but expects a string instead.

Instead you could try using:

```py
df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("first_name").map_elements(lambda first_name: jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(first_name, name)).alias("jwm")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("jwm") >= 0.8).then(1).otherwise(0).alias("COMP80_FN")
    )
)
```